# Why Exaile can not read my music folder with special chars?

Tags: 12.04, encoding, exaile

I'm using Exaile 0.3.2.2 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The system language is configured to `pt-BR.utf8`, so my music folder is called `/home/<login>/Música` ( notice the *ú* ).

When I add this folder to Exaile library, it is displayed as `/home/<login>/M%C3%BAsica` and none of the files is displayed in Library.

I suppose there is some bug when parsing the folder name, so how can I make Exaile correctly read this **without renaming the folder nor upgrading the system**?

Comment: I think the question is relevant, since the problem can be reproduced and it's worth knowing that a system reboot might help.

Comment: If you can reproduce it where a reboot *doesn't* work, then it is an issue. Right now the problem is fixed and no one knows how or why (other than reboot, which is really ambiguous). If someone else has the same issue they should ask a new question (after trying a reboot of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**
I've done a test and the musics in the directory previously added to the library appear after you quit the application and restarted it. A system reboot **is not nedded**.

First answer was: After a system reboot, it just worked. I don't know how to explain what happened.